# ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID utilizing Heroku ACM

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate

I am utilizing Heroku Automated Certificate Management (ACM) and some of my users have started to receive ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID messages when visiting my site and cannot access the site via https. It looks like a root certificate (DST Root CA X3) has expired but as Heroku is managing this I have no clue how to fix this problem. I have submitted a ticket with them but that can take 24-48 hours and I can't have my users down for that long. Is there an immediate fix I can do on my end that does't cost me $1,000 paying for support I only need for this issue?

Comment: this is the reason: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/

in the meantime, you can move behind cloudflare and let them issue a certificate for you

Comment: Yeah, I saw that article too but there has got to be something I can do to resolve this. I have never used Cloudfare before but looking at their status page they are dealing with issues today as well. Not sure I should attempt that option as I would be messing with a live site that only a few users can't use to potentially disconnected all of my users depending on what their issues are.

Comment: Looks like Herok just updated their status to show this as an issue. Heroku - Engineering is investigating issues with missing metrics, the Heroku Connect dashboard not loading for some users, and some applications having expired or invalid ACM-issued certificates. Heroku data services and Heroku Connect Sync and OData are operating normally.

Comment: Heroku gave a further update to contact support regarding this issue: "Engineering has determined that the issue regarding expired or invalid certificates is not related to the Heroku platform but the expiry of the Let's Encrypt Root CA X3 on September 30 at 14:01 GMT. Customers should reach out to Heroku Support if they need assistance or feedback on updating their clients or apps to not use the now-expired X3 root. - SEP 30, 2021 17:41 UTC"